# PgAdmin III not responding when trying to restore a database

Tags: postgresql-9.1, database-restore, pgadmin, pg-restore

I'm trying to restore a database (via a backup file), I'm on PgAdmin III (Postgresql 9.1).
After choosing the backup file, a window indicating that pg_restore.exe is running then PgAdmin is not responding ,it has been few hours (It is not a RAM shortage issue)

It might be due the backup file size (500 MB), but i have already restored a database with a 300 MB backup file few days ago, and it was done smoothly.
By the way the format of the backup file ( created via pg_dump)is the "tar" format.

Please let me know if anything comes to mind or if you need any more information. I appreciate any help or pointers anyone has. Thanks in advance.

Comment: PgAdmin-III doesn't run dumps and restores in a background thread. So the UI will block until `pg_restore` finishes or returns some output. Check the task manager to see that pg_restore is actually doing something (using some cpu / doing some disk I/O). It could be blocked on a lock I guess; check `pg_locks`.

Comment: I've cheked the task manager, the pg_restore process is running, I didn't get what you meant by " check pg_locks" , would you please elaborate?
I increased the pripority of the pg_restore process, and I'm still waiting

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I solved looking this [web site tutorial](http://suite.opengeo.org/4.1/dataadmin/pgDBAdmin/backup.html)

File has been generated in my backup with the size of 78 MB, I have generated it again using

- Format:Custom
- Ratio:
- Enconding: UTF8
- Rolename:postgres

I try to restore again and then works fine.

Comment: The tutorial you've linked to may show how to fix the problem, but you should summarize linked content in your answer itself so it's still useful if the linked content changes or becomes unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X I had similar issues. After selecting the .backup file and clicking restore in pgAdmin I got the spinning beachball. Everything however was working in the background, the UI was just hanging.

One way you can check that everything is working is by looking at Activity Monitor on OS X or Resource Monitor on Windows. If you look at the 'Disk' tab you should see activity from postgres and you should see the value in the 'Bytes Read' column slowly going up.  I was restoring a ~15G backup and the counter in the 'Bytes Read' column slowly counted up and up. When it got to 15G it finished without errors and the pgAdmin UI became active again.

(BTW, my 15G restore took about 1.5 hours on a Mac with an i7 and 8G of RAM)